# "ERROR:Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" has occurred in LibSBMLSim(SBML=Systems Biology Markup Language)

Tags: c

I tried to use LibSBMLSim as api in c language.
I referenced https://fun.bio.keio.ac.jp/software/libsbmlsim/ and installed both LibSBML and LibSBMLSim.Then I made c file like below:

```
/* Example C, C++ code */
#include "libsbmlsim/libsbmlsim.h"
int main(void) {
  /*
   * Simulate sbml.xml to time=20 with dt=0.1, print_interval=10
   * by 4th-order Runge-Kutta Method.
   */
  myResult *r = simulateSBMLFromFile("sbml.xml", 20, 0.1, 10, 0, MTHD_RUNGE_KUTTA, 0);
  write_csv(r, "result.csv"); /* Export simulation result as CSV file */
  free_myResult(r);           /* Free Result object */
  return 0;
}
```

And executed "gcc test.c -o test", but error has occurred. Error messages are below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_free_myResult", referenced from:
      _main in test-f56b85.o
  "_simulateSBMLFromFile", referenced from:
      _main in test-f56b85.o
  "_write_csv", referenced from:
      _main in test-f56b85.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I checked /usr/local/include/libsbmlsim/libsbmlsim.h, there specified free_myResult function.
I tried a lot but it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: You need to specify the library on the command line. Perhaps `-lSBMLSIM` but you need to look for the `.a` or `.dylib` (if you’re on a Mac as I suspect) or `.so` and use that name minus the `lib` prefix and the suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I checked /usr/local/include/libsbmlsim/libsbmlsim.h, there specified free_myResult function.

That only confirms that the prototypes are present. But when you compile, you need to tell what library to use to find those symbols. So you need to link with the library using `-lsbmlsim` and probably specify the location of where to search for the library using `-L` and the location of header files using `-I` too -- all these in your command line.

Alternatively you can use a [Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html). Have a look at the [Makefile](https://github.com/libsbmlsim/libsbmlsim/blob/master/examples/c/Makefile) provided in the libsbmlsim's example.

Comment: I could execute, when I reference makefile. Thanks very much.